# Android RecyclerView cache

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Tenho um recyrcleview em maioria dos dispositivos funcionou bem, porém em alguns dispositivos na versão 7, ele da uma bugada, fica tipo com cache dos primeiros elementos. Alguém tem alguma ideia? exemplo da foto funcionando normal mais caso é rolado ele começa a bugar. Desde já agradeço a atenção

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
public class AlvosAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AlvosAdapter.ViewHolder> {
int TEMPO_CLICK_BUTTON = 400;

public interface OnItemClickListener {
    void onItemClick(AlvosResultado item);
}


private final List<AlvosResultado> items;
private final OnItemClickListener listener;


public AlvosAdapter(List<AlvosResultado> items, OnItemClickListener listener) {
    this.items = items;
    this.listener = listener;
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_lista_alvos, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(v);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    holder.bind(items.get(position), listener);
    holder.alfa.setTag(position);
    holder.delta.setTag(position);
    holder.charlie.setTag(position);
    holder.procedure.setTag(position);
    holder.nooshoot.setTag(position);
    holder.miss.setTag(position);

    holder.alfa.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        long start = 0, finish = 0, total = 0;

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                start = System.currentTimeMillis();
            } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                finish = System.currentTimeMillis();
                total = finish - start;
                if (total <= TEMPO_CLICK_BUTTON) {
                    if (holder.alvo.getText().subSequence(0, 1).equals("T") || holder.alvo.getText().subSequence(0, 2).equals("DT")) {
                        String a = String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(holder.alfa.getText().toString()) + 1);
                        items.get(position).setAlfa(String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(items.get(position).getAlfa()) + 1));
                        holder.alfa.setText(a);
                        AlvosActivity.alvos[0] += 1;
                    } else {
                        String a = String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(holder.alfa.getText().toString()) + 1);
                        if (holder.miss.getText().equals("1")) {
                            holder.miss.setText("0");
                            holder.alfa.setText("1");
                            addAcertoAlvo(0);
                            tirarAcertoAlvo(3);
                            items.get(position).setMiss("0");
                            items.get(position).setAlfa("1");
                            AlvosActivity.preencherTotalPontos(AlvosActivity.btMiss, AlvosActivity.alvos[3].toString());
                        } else if (holder.alfa.getText().equals("1")) {
                            mensagemAlvos(v.getContext());
                        } else {
                            items.get(position).setAlfa(String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(items.get(position).getAlfa()) + 1));
                            holder.alfa.setText(a);
                            addAcertoAlvo(0);
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    if (Integer.parseInt(holder.alfa.getText().toString()) >= 0) {
                        AlvosActivity.alvos[0] -= Integer.parseInt(holder.alfa.getText().toString());
                        items.get(position).setAlfa("0");
                        holder.alfa.setText("0");
                    }
                }
                AlvosActivity.checkSelecionadoZerar();
                AlvosActivity.calcularHitFactor();
                AlvosActivity.preencherTotalPontos(AlvosActivity.btAlfa, AlvosActivity.alvos[0].toString());
                color(holder);
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
    holder.charlie.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        long start = 0, finish = 0, total = 0;

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                start = System.currentTimeMillis();
            } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                finish = System.currentTimeMillis();
                total = finish - start;
                if (total <= TEMPO_CLICK_BUTTON) {
                    if (holder.alvo.getText().subSequence(0, 1).equals("T") || holder.alvo.getText().subSequence(0, 2).equals("DT")) {
                        String a = String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(holder.charlie.getText().toString()) + 1);
                        holder.charlie.setText(a);
                        AlvosActivity.alvos[1] += 1;
                        items.get(position).setCharlie(String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(items.get(position).getCharlie()) + 1));
                    }
                } else {
                    if (Integer.parseInt(holder.charlie.getText().toString()) >= 0) {
                        AlvosActivity.alvos[1] -= Integer.parseInt(holder.charlie.getText().toString());
                        items.get(position).setCharlie("0");
                        holder.charlie.setText("0");
                    }
                }
                AlvosActivity.checkSelecionadoZerar();
                AlvosActivity.calcularHitFactor();
                color(holder);
                AlvosActivity.preencherTotalPontos(AlvosActivity.btCharlie, AlvosActivity.alvos[1].toString());
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
    holder.delta.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        long start = 0, finish = 0, total = 0;

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                start = System.currentTimeMillis();
            } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                finish = System.currentTimeMillis();
                total = finish - start;
                if (total <= TEMPO_CLICK_BUTTON) {
                    if (holder.alvo.getText().subSequence(0, 1).equals("T") || holder.alvo.getText().subSequence(0, 2).equals("DT")) {
                        String a = String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(holder.delta.getText().toString()) + 1);
                        holder.delta.setText(a);
                        AlvosActivity.alvos[2] += 1;
                        items.get(position).setDelta(String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(items.get(position).getDelta()) + 1));
                    }
                } else {
                    if (Integer.parseInt(holder.delta.getText().toString()) >= 0) {
                        AlvosActivity.alvos[2] -= Integer.parseInt(holder.delta.getText().toString());
                        items.get(position).setDelta("0");
                        holder.delta.setText("0");
                    }
                }
                AlvosActivity.checkSelecionadoZerar();
                AlvosActivity.calcularHitFactor();
                AlvosActivity.preencherTotalPontos(AlvosActivity.btDelta, AlvosActivity.alvos[2].toString());
                color(holder);
            }
            return true;
        }
    });

    holder.miss.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        long start = 0, finish = 0, total = 0;

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                start = System.currentTimeMillis();
            } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                finish = System.currentTimeMillis();
                total = finish - start;
                if (total <= TEMPO_CLICK_BUTTON) {
                    if (holder.alvo.getText().subSequence(0, 1).equals("T") || holder.alvo.getText().subSequence(0, 2).equals("DT")) {
                        String a = String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(holder.miss.getText().toString()) + 1);
                        holder.miss.setText(a);
                        AlvosActivity.alvos[3] += 1;
                        items.get(position).setMiss(String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(items.get(position).getMiss()) + 1));
                    } else {
                        String a = String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(holder.miss.getText().toString()) + 1);
                        if (holder.alfa.getText().equals("1")) {
                            holder.alfa.setText("0");
                            holder.miss.setText("1");
                            addAcertoAlvo(3);
                            tirarAcertoAlvo(0);
                            items.get(position).setMiss("1");
                            items.get(position).setAlfa("0");
                            AlvosActivity.preencherTotalPontos(AlvosActivity.btAlfa, AlvosActivity.alvos[0].toString());
                        } else if (holder.miss.getText().equals("1")) {
                            mensagemAlvos(v.getContext());
                        } else {
                            AlvosActivity.alvos[3] += 1;
                            holder.miss.setText(a);
                            items.get(position).setMiss(String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(items.get(position).getMiss()) + 1));
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    if (Integer.parseInt(holder.miss.getText().toString()) >= 0) {
                        AlvosActivity.alvos[3] -= Integer.parseInt(holder.miss.getText().toString());
                        items.get(position).setMiss("0");
                        holder.miss.setText("0");
                    }
                }
                AlvosActivity.checkSelecionadoZerar();
                AlvosActivity.calcularHitFactor();
                AlvosActivity.preencherTotalPontos(AlvosActivity.btMiss, AlvosActivity.alvos[3].toString());
                color(holder);
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
    holder.nooshoot.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        long start = 0, finish = 0, total = 0;

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                start = System.currentTimeMillis();
            } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                finish = System.currentTimeMillis();
                total = finish - start;
                if (total <= TEMPO_CLICK_BUTTON) {
                    String a = String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(holder.nooshoot.getText().toString()) + 1);
                    holder.nooshoot.setText(a);
                    AlvosActivity.alvos[4] += 1;
                    items.get(position).setNooShoot(String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(items.get(position).getNooShoot()) + 1));
                } else {
                    if (Integer.parseInt(holder.nooshoot.getText().toString()) >= 0) {
                        AlvosActivity.alvos[4] -= Integer.parseInt(holder.nooshoot.getText().toString());
                        items.get(position).setNooShoot("0");
                        holder.nooshoot.setText("0");
                    }
                }
                AlvosActivity.checkSelecionadoZerar();
                AlvosActivity.calcularHitFactor();
                AlvosActivity.preencherTotalPontos(AlvosActivity.btNoshoot, AlvosActivity.alvos[4].toString());
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
    holder.procedure.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        long start = 0, finish = 0, total = 0;

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                start = System.currentTimeMillis();
            } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                finish = System.currentTimeMillis();
                total = finish - start;
                if (total <= TEMPO_CLICK_BUTTON) {
                    String a = String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(holder.procedure.getText().toString()) + 1);
                    holder.procedure.setText(a);
                    AlvosActivity.alvos[5] += 1;
                    items.get(position).setProcedure(String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(items.get(position).getProcedure()) + 1));
                } else {
                    if (Integer.parseInt(holder.procedure.getText().toString()) >= 0) {
                        AlvosActivity.alvos[5] -= Integer.parseInt(holder.procedure.getText().toString());
                        items.get(position).setProcedure("0");
                        holder.procedure.setText("0");
                        AlvosActivity.checkSelecionadoZerar();
                    }
                }
                AlvosActivity.checkSelecionadoZerar();
                AlvosActivity.calcularHitFactor();
                AlvosActivity.preencherTotalPontos(AlvosActivity.btProcedure, AlvosActivity.alvos[5].toString());
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
}

public static void mensagemAlvos(Context context) {
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context,
            "Alvo não pode ter mais de 1 hits", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    toast.setGravity(Gravity.TOP | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 0, 0);
    toast.show();
}

public static void addAcertoAlvo(int pos) {
    try {
        AlvosActivity.alvos[pos] += 1;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        AlvosActivity.alvos[pos] = 1;
    }
}

public void tirarAcertoAlvo(int pos) {
    try {
        AlvosActivity.alvos[pos] -= 1;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        AlvosActivity.alvos[pos] = 0;
    }
}

public void color(ViewHolder holder) {
    if (holder.alvo.getText().subSequence(0, 1).equals("T") || holder.alvo.getText().subSequence(0, 2).equals("DT")) {
        int soma = Integer.parseInt(holder.alfa.getText().toString()) + Integer.parseInt(holder.delta.getText().toString()) + Integer.parseInt(holder.charlie.getText().toString()) + Integer.parseInt(holder.miss.getText().toString());
        if (soma >= 3) {
            mudarCorFundoPapeis(R.drawable.cell_red, holder.alfa, holder.delta, holder.charlie, holder.miss);
        } else if (soma == 1) {
            mudarCorFundoPapeis(R.drawable.cell_green, holder.alfa, holder.delta, holder.charlie, holder.miss);
        } else if (soma == 2) {
            mudarCorFundoPapeis(R.drawable.cell_green2, holder.alfa, holder.delta, holder.charlie, holder.miss);
        } else {
            mudarCorFundoPapeis(R.drawable.cell_shape, holder.alfa, holder.delta, holder.charlie, holder.miss);
        }
    } else {
        int soma = Integer.parseInt(holder.alfa.getText().toString()) + Integer.parseInt(holder.miss.getText().toString());
        if (soma >= 1) {
            mudarCorFundoMetais(R.drawable.cell_green2, holder.alfa, holder.miss);
        } else {
            mudarCorFundoMetais(R.drawable.cell_shape, holder.alfa, holder.miss);
        }
    }
}

public static void mudarCorFundoPapeis(int drawable, Button alfa, Button delta, Button charlie, Button miss) {
    alfa.setBackgroundResource(drawable);
    delta.setBackgroundResource(drawable);
    charlie.setBackgroundResource(drawable);
    miss.setBackgroundResource(drawable);
}

public static void mudarCorFundoMetais(int drawable, Button alfa, Button miss) {
    alfa.setBackgroundResource(drawable);
    miss.setBackgroundResource(drawable);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return items.size();
}

static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    private Button alvo;
    private Button alfa;
    private Button delta;
    private Button charlie;
    private Button miss;
    private Button nooshoot;
    private Button procedure;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        alvo = itemView.findViewById(R.id.btAlvo);
        alfa = itemView.findViewById(R.id.btAlfa);
        delta = itemView.findViewById(R.id.btDelta);
        charlie = itemView.findViewById(R.id.btCharlie);
        miss = itemView.findViewById(R.id.btMiss);
        nooshoot = itemView.findViewById(R.id.btNoShoot);
        procedure = itemView.findViewById(R.id.btProcedure);
    }

    public void bind(final AlvosResultado item, final OnItemClickListener listener) {
        AlvosActivity.recycler.setRecycledViewPool(new RecyclerView.RecycledViewPool());
        AlvosActivity.recycler.getRecycledViewPool().clear();
        alvo.setText(item.getAlvo());
        alfa.setText(item.getAlfa());
        charlie.setText(item.getCharlie());
        delta.setText(item.getDelta());
        miss.setText(item.getMiss());
        nooshoot.setText(item.getNooShoot());
        procedure.setText(item.getProcedure());
        if (!alvo.getText().subSequence(0, 1).equals("T") && !alvo.getText().subSequence(0, 2).equals("DT")) {
            int soma = Integer.parseInt(item.getAlfa()) + Integer.parseInt(item.getMiss());
            delta.setEnabled(false);
            PorterDuffColorFilter colorFilter = new PorterDuffColorFilter(Color.GRAY, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
            delta.getBackground().setColorFilter(colorFilter);
            delta.setText("");
            charlie.setEnabled(false);
            charlie.getBackground().setColorFilter(colorFilter);
            charlie.setText("");
            if (soma >= 1) {
                mudarCorFundoMetais(R.drawable.cell_green2, alfa, miss);
            }
        } else {
            int soma = Integer.parseInt(item.getAlfa()) + Integer.parseInt(item.getMiss()) + Integer.parseInt(item.getDelta()) + Integer.parseInt(item.getCharlie());
            if (soma >= 3) {
                mudarCorFundoPapeis(R.drawable.cell_red, alfa, delta, charlie, miss);
            } else if (soma == 1) {
                mudarCorFundoPapeis(R.drawable.cell_green, alfa, delta, charlie, miss);
            } else if (soma == 2) {
                mudarCorFundoPapeis(R.drawable.cell_green2, alfa, delta, charlie, miss);
            } else {
                mudarCorFundoPapeis(R.drawable.cell_shape, alfa, delta, charlie, miss);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

os itens

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
android:shrinkColumns="*"
android:stretchColumns="*">

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btAlvo"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/cell_shape"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="10dip"
        android:text="P1"
        android:layout_marginRight="3px"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btAlfa"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/cell_shape"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="A1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="3px"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btCharlie"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/cell_shape"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="A1" />

    <Button
        android:layout_marginRight="3px"
        android:id="@+id/btDelta"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/cell_shape"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="10dip"
        android:text="C1" />

    <Button
        android:layout_marginLeft="3px"
        android:id="@+id/btMiss"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/cell_shape"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="10dip"
        android:text="D1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btNoShoot"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/cell_shape"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="10dip"
        android:text="M1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btProcedure"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/cell_shape"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="10dip"
        android:text="N1"
        android:layout_marginRight="6px"/>
</TableRow>
```

Comment: Consegui no else final coloquei isso e funcionou

Comment: delta.setEnabled(true);
                charlie.setEnabled(true);
                delta.setBackgroundResource(R.color.colorBackground);
                charlie.setBackgroundResource(R.color.colorBackground);